# What does it mean for a function to have rapid decrease on a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, definition, compactness

I was reading a book where the authors make use of the space $C_{0}(X)$, which is the space of all functions defined on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ which "goes to zero at infinity". In the book, I could not find the meaning of "goes to zero at infinity" for functions defined on topological spaces. Is there a general definition for such a concept? I was thinking something like "given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some open set $U$ such that $|f(x)|< \epsilon$ if $x \in X\setminus U$". Is this a correct definition?

Answer (score 3):

No. The correct definition is: for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that$$\left(\forall x\in K^\complement\right):\bigl|f(x)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$For instance, with this definition the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\x&\mapsto&e^{-x^2}\end{array}$$belongs to $C_0(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Note that this definition is made so that $C_0(X)$ is equal to the set of restrictions to $X$ of all $f \in C(\alpha X)$ that obey $f(\infty)=0$.